# Change embeded Macro to VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a embeded macro in a combo box of a DB and I want to change it to vba and I tried to Convert macros to VB and it wont.... Anyway here it is:

Record: First
Where Condition: ="[EmpID] = " & Str(Nz([Screen].[ActiveControl],0))

Comment: And what is the macro supposed to do?

Comment: When I select an employee from the combo box it goes to that employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using in the *AfterUpdate* event of combobox:

```
' Set filter.
Me.Filter = "[EmpID] = " & Nz(Me!NameOfYourComboBox.Value, 0) & ""
' Activate filter.
Me.FilterOn = True
```